# Add existing Android Studio project to VSTS

Tags: android-studio, azure-devops, tfvc, team-explorer-everywhere

I have an existing Android project developed in Android Studio using Kotlin. It's not yet under version control. I'd like to add it to Visual Studio Team Services in a new classic TFVC project, not a Git project. Can anyone explain how to do this, or point me to a tutorial?

I have installed the Team Services plugin and configured the TF executable, but now I'm going around in circles trying to associate my project with a new or existing TFVC project. I see an option to import into a Git TFS project, but nothing for TFVC. Nothing seems to quite do what I need.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After install the team services plugin, you should also **install [TF command line tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases)**:

Download `TFF_CLC-14.*.*.zip` (`TFF_CLC_14.120.0.zip` for now) -> extract the .zip file in a certain directory -> in commandline/terminal -> cd to the extract files -> `tf eula` -> finish reading -> press `y`.

More detail steps, you can refer [TFVC support](http://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/intelliJ#_tfvc-support).

Then **configure the TF in android studio**:

File -> settings -> version control -> TFVC -> select the file `tf.cmd` (for windows) in the path that you extract -> test to check if it’s valid -> OK.

[image]

Now you have configure the TFVC VCS totally in android studio.

For android studio, it can’t import project into VSTS TFVC repo directly. As you found, it can just import into VSTS Git repo.

You should checkout from VSTS TFVC repo (VCS -> checkout from version control -> team services TFVC).
For MAC OS, the [TFVC options/commands in android studio can use used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCOGW5u9tO8). But unfortunately, for windows OS, it can only checkout TFVC repo, the TFVC options/commands is not available. If you are using windows OS, you can feed back the issue in android studio -> help -> submit feedback.

The work around for now is that you can **config and map the TFVC repo in visual studio**, then copy your android projects in the map directory and then add them in source control, finally checkin the changes to VSTS. Details steps as below:

#### 1. Connect with VSTS project

VS -> team explorer -> manage connections -> connect to team project -> input your VSTS credential -> select the VSTS project -> connect.

[image]

#### 2.Config and map TFVC repo locally

Configure workspace -> select a local path -> Map & Get.

[image]

#### 3. Add android project to source control

Copy the android project to the local map path (in above step) -> VS -> source control explorer -> make sure the workspace and local path are correct -> add items to folder -> select the project you copied -> finish.

[image]

#### 4. Checkin changes to VSTS

Team explorer -> pending changes -> (add comment) -> checkin.

Now the android studio project is added to VSTS.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create this excellent answer Marina. It was very helpful and got me past my problem! Andy

Comment: Just a note that in stage 3 I excluded the .gradle and app/build directories when adding the project to source control.

Comment: Yeah, it's reasonable. The files and folders which not necessary to be version controlled can be excluded.