# Adding Existing Android Project into VSTS via Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, azure-devops

I need to know how to add existing Android project into VSTS.

I have gone through the steps to set up VSTS with Studio and I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700947/add-existing-android-studio-project-to-vsts#) link  but at the end it says:

> it can't be done directly through Studio and Window OS.

Any better answer or updates for direct upload from Android Studio will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly did you do? At what point did you get an error? What is the exact error message?

Comment: I did not got any error .. i am using windows OS and Android Studio .. there is a line in answer of previous link which says it cannot import directly through Android Studio and provides a work around through Visual Studio which is another IDE . I need to know if there is a way through Studio only ?

Comment: According to your tag, are you using git as your source control ?

Answer (score 1):

You can install "Visual Studio Team Services Plugin for Android Studio".

The Visual Studio Team Services Plugin for Android Studio allows you to connect to your Git repositories on Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and Team Foundation Server (TFS) in a seamless and intuitive way. You can also use this plugin to import your android development projects into VSTS or create pull requests in your VSTS/TFS Git repository.

*Note: The plugin is compatible with Android Studio 1.2 and up.*

The Team Services plugin for Android Studio is available in the [Android Studio Plugin Repository](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-visual-studio-team-services) once you download it follow the following instructions:

1. In Android Studio, open plugin settings. (from the `File` menu, select `Settings...` then `Plugins`).
2. Click the `Install plugin from disk...` button and browse to the JAR file on disk.
3. Click the `Install plugin` button and restart Android Studio.

The plugin can be installed from Android Studio by browsing the Plugin Repository:

1. In Android Studio, open plugin settings. (from the `File` menu, select `Settings...` then `Plugins`).
2. Click the `Browse repositories...` button and search for "Visual Studio Team Services".
3. Click the `Install plugin` button and restart Android Studio.

Comment: done with this  ... please let me know how can i add my existing studio project to vsts repository

Comment: In the menu click on "VCS" then click "Import into source control". please see this viedo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7bpC6KwrA4 is for IntelliJ but it's the same for Andriod Studio.

Answer (score 0):

First please follow the tutorial link in VSTS:  [Android Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/java/download-android-studio-plug-in?view=vsts) to make the plug-in works well.

And you can also **watch a how-to video** on importing projects on our [YouTube channel.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7bpC6KwrA4)

*Note: Also make sure you have enough permission with the team project in TFS which you want to import in.*

Since you are using Git, if you already have local git repo and project, you could directly select **Import into Version Control** and select **import into Team Service Git**.

[image]